# Output files have same duplicate rows using Powershell scripts

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I m using this PowerShell scripts just to fetch SQL Server version as below

```
Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance "DESKTOP-6U9IKQD" | Invoke-DbaQuery -File "C:\test.sql" | Out-File C:\output.csv
```

This is my test.sql file

[image: test.sql]

and this is the output.csv file

[image: output.csv]

Supposed to be one row for the output but why I can see many duplicate rows. Anything need to change in scripts?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). II suspect that you want to use the [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) rather than the `Out-File` cmdlet.

Comment: _Anything need to change in scripts?_ Yes. Since you don't supply the `-Database` parameter `Get-DbaDatabase` returns one object for each database on the server, so you'll see output for master, model, msdb and tempdb, plus any user databases you might have.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaDatabase) it looks like the query is run against each individual database when the `-Database` switch is omitted, so of course you'll get multiple lines; one for each database you have (It seems you have 6).